# Django: how to perform and display calculations on inputs obtained from a form post?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have successfuly created a complex form with a lot of fields using ModelForm and FormView. I managed to save those data and display it in the admin. Thus it is only the beginning of what I want to do.

My next goal is to use the inputs posted by the user via the form to perform calculations on it and then display the results of those calculations in another view.

What would be the best approach to do so? So far here are my files (I do not display all the fields since it is not relevant)

Here is the view I use to display the form

```
class SimulInputView(FormView):
    form_class = SimulInputForm
    template_name = 'apps/simulateur/formulaire/form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('simulateur_results')

    def get_initial(self):
        initial_data = super(SimulInputView, self).get_initial()
        for key, value in dict_simul_form_default_data.items():
            initial_data[key] = value
        return initial_data

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['data'] = SimulateurData
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

How should I modify my form_valid function to use another module which would perform calculations on the form data received before displaying them in another view?

**EDIT**

I modified my code as following. It seems to work well but I would like to know if it's good practice to handle it this way. Could you please share your opinion?

```
# VIEWS

class SimulInputView(FormView):
    form_class = SimulInputForm
    template_name = 'apps/simulateur/simulateur_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # save form and put in data_instance to get its id later
        data_instance = form.save()
        # save form data
        form_data = form.data
        # call calculs_simulation.py script which performs calculations on form data
        result = calculs_simulation(form_data)
        # put results of  calculation in SimulResult model, and set the id for SimulInput foreignkey
        result_model = SimulResult(simulinput_id=data_instance.id, **result)
        # save the result model and get its id
        result_model.save()
        result_model_id = result_model.id
        return redirect('simulateur_results', result_model_id)

class SimulResultView(DetailView):
    model = SimulResult
    template_name = 'apps/simulateur/simulateur_results.html'

# URLS

urlpatterns = [
    path('formulaire/', simul_input_views.SimulInputView.as_view(), name="simulateur_form"),
    path('resultats/<int:pk>/', simul_result_views.SimulResultView.as_view(), name="simulateur_results"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return to another view with the i stance of the data saved to display the results you need. For example,

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    .
    .
    data_instance = form.save()
    return redirect(reverse('results_view', args=(data_instance.id, )))
```

Now in your results_view you can get your data_instance by id and calculate then render your results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell how do you then write the get function in results_view to get the data_instance and use it?

Once I have pass the data to results_view, what is the best way to perform calculations on them? Can I have a separate file like calculation.py who will do that? Then, how do I pass the data to it to perform the calculations and then send the results back to my results_view ? 

Quite lots of question but I really struggle to find the proper way to do it.

Comment: I edited my question with the solution I came up with. Could you please tell me what do you think about it? I had a hard time figuring out how to do it. I thought such patterns were easier and better documented.

Comment: so far so good! I had a hard time figuring this one out. Thanks for your help, I do not think I would have found this solution without your hint